# A is an operator. Proof that $\ker(A^*A)=\ker(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the proof for $\ker(A^*A) =\ker(A)$?
I tried to look it up in a course but found no clues.

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to see $\ker(A)\subseteq\ker(A^{\ast}A)$. Assume now $x\in\ker(A^{\ast}A)$, then $\|Ax\|^{2}=\left<Ax,Ax\right>=\left<x,A^{\ast}Ax\right>=\left<x,0\right>=0$, so $\|Ax\|=0$, so $Ax=0$, that is, $x\in\ker(A)$.